# Calculate date between two date and sum then convert into hours and minutes

Tags: sql-server

I want to get the Date difference in hours and minutes and to achieve that I have used this query in SQL Server:

```
Cast(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, fromtime, totime) / 60 / 60 % 24) as varchar(20)) + ' hours '
+CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, fromtime, totime) / 60 % 60)as varchar(20))+' minutes '  as [TotalTime]
```

It returns the following Output:

```
TotalTime
---------------------
16 Hours 120 Minutes 
3 Hours 90 Minutes
```

but the expected output is:

```
TotalTime
----------------------
18 Hours 0 Minutes 
4 Hours 30 Minutes.
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Your query is correct, it should return the expected output !!

Comment: Post the sample values in fromtime & totime

Comment: I have tested the query with sample values and it returns the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is perfect, All you need to do is to write a outer query over it. Something like below

```
select case when t.minutes>60 then t.hours+(t.minutes/60) else t.hours end as hours,
       case when t.minutes>60 then t.minutes%60 else t.minutes end as minutes
from
(
select 
Cast(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, fromtime, totime) / 60 / 60 % 24) as varchar(20)) as hours
+CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, fromtime, totime) / 60 % 60)as varchar(20)) as minutes
from tablename
)as t
```